# layout already exists use a different qualifier

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to support screens size by create each layouts on *Android Studio* 3.1.3
i use the following steps to create one xml for example **XXXHDPI** :

**Preview > Orientation for Preview  > Create Other > Density** and from **Density** i choose **XXXHDPI** ,the layout-xxxhdpi of my Activity will created.

but *Android Studio* 3.2 i can't do that when i try to create layout i get this message :

> layout already exists use a different qualifier

[image]

Comment: did you checked on the location? it may already exists

Comment: @SurajVaishnav yeah , it doesn't exist i get this message on every layout i want to create it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are following these steps:

> Right click on res folder=> New => Android Resource directory => Then
>   a dialog appear => Resource type from dropdown => select layout => and
>   from qualifier => click on density => >> => then your desired density

Or you can do(**This will definitely work**)

**Create folder by yourself**

> right click on res=> show in explorer=> under res folder=> create a
>   new folder=> rename it to => layout-xxxhdpi

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the directory of `res/layout-xxxhdpi` and it wasn't there so probably that might be a bug. But, you can however try to add the directory manually.

Just go to `/res` folder of your project and add a new folder called `layout-xxxhdpi`.

---

Please use issue tracker or, report a bug of the Android Studio by clicking on the `Help -> Report a bug` if you insist that it does not exist in there.

**Read:** https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs#studio-bugs

Answer (score -1):

You can create in explorer. For first activity you can create in android studio. But for other activities you can use this steps:

- right click on activity that u want to create large or x-large activity
- show in explorer
- copy xml file
- go to main/res/large-layout in explorer and paste it then close explore.

It works successfully and large activity will appear in android studio.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]